# How to Calculate YTD (Jan to prev month) in a single column in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Original post - https://community.tableau.com/thread/206909

I have a report in which I have sales per month in the column and commodities in the row. The data show actual sales and future estimates for each month.
[image]

Need to calculate Year-To-Date (YTD) total for 2016 (from Jan to Previous month) and have it in a single column at the end of the actual values.

I already created a calculated field - YTD

```
IF 
   YEAR([DATE]) = YEAR(NOW())
AND
   MONTH([DATE])< MONTH(NOW())
THEN
   [VALUE/UNIT]
ELSE
    0
END
```

But when I add to the view, it creates a another section for YTD  with sum for each month till April.

Can someone please help me in how to achieve this in Tableau?

Comment: That isn't Oracle syntax. Is Tableau translating that, or are you actually using a different DBMS?

Comment: That's Tableau calculated field. I'm using oracle for connection

Comment: Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to achieve this view in Tableau
1. To create calculated field for each Month and YTD and add measure names in Row & Measure values in Text 
2. Make union of 2 queries - one that select all the correct values & second that have YTD calculation in month column. Then use pivot it